# Why is my media screen not working for a specific tag?

Tags: css

my media screen does not seem to be responsive to my pages tag. Not sure if there is an order problem but would love some help.

I have tried looking this up on w3schools and on here but cant seem to figure it out

```
 .pages {
  margin-left: 2%;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: yellow;
}

a:hover {
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .egg {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .cheese {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .croissant {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .pages {
    margin-left: 5%;
  }
}
```

I am expecting the margin to change in .pages but with no luck!

Comment: Adding your HTML code also will be more helpful. At present, it is difficult to detect the problem.

Comment: `max-width: 400px;` means very little screen size, isn't it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/hendrikwegner/pen/oOQJPb) as a simple example

```
<div class="foo">foo</div>
```

```css
.foo {
  background-color:red;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px){
  .foo {
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 10%;
  }
}
```

A good practice is starting mobile-first with your css styling so you only have to change relevant things on viewport-changes and avoid code duplication. So you start with your mobile styling without a @media-query and work your way up and add `min-width` media-querys.

Comment: This reads like a game of spot-the-difference. What did you change that should solve the problem?

Comment: Pasting the given code by the op into a codepen shows that it's working. My guess is that you are just not able to make the browser window thin enough to fit into the max-width: 400px. You can check your actual window size in chrome when you have the developer tool open

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
@media only screen  and (min-device-width : 400px) {

 classes here

 }
```

Only specify size of classes/IDs/tags inside the {..}

Comment: No. Having rulesets both outside and inside media queries is fine.

Comment: technically yes, but for the change inside the confined query.

Comment: Which is what the code in the question is already doing